# Knockout.js - mouseover and mouseout not working properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying working with knockout.js - mouseover and mouseout. I am bit new with Knockout. What I have done below:

```
 <h2 id="popup" data-bind="event: { mouseover: PK.showdiv, mouseout: PK.hidediv }">
                Search
 </h2>
```

and I have my script block like below:

```
@section Javascript
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        PK.showdiv = function () {
            alert("Showed");
        };
        PK.hidedivOver = function () {
            alert("Hidden");
        };
    })
```

This works fine if I use normal JavaScript call with "onmouseover" or "onmouseout". But the knockout.js call like data-bind with events is not working.

I am using MVC with Razor view.

Comment: Is that all of your code? If so, you are not binding properly. You have no call to `ko.applyBindings()`, and no viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created some example in jsFiddle [Click here to see an example](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/bxeBZ/)

So, in general I've created two functions on my ViewModel with names 'showdiv' and 'hidediv'
**Javascript Code:**

*Note: we should apply bindings for our viewModel in the bottom of our js code (calling ko.applyBindings(new viewModel()); )*

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.action = ko.observable("Hidden");
    self.showdiv = function () {
        //alert('Showed');
        self.action("Showed");
        $('#mySpan').addClass('redColor');
    };

    self.hidediv = function () {
        //alert('Hidden');
        self.action("Hidden");
        $('#mySpan').removeClass('redColor');           
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div data-bind="event: { mouseover: showdiv, mouseout: hidediv }">Search</div>
<span id="mySpan" data-bind="text: action"></span>
```

**CSS Code**

```
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
span{
  margin: 20px;
}
.redColor{
  color: red;
}
```

**START EDIT**
Sorry, forgot to mention your mistakes:

**1.** You didn't initialize PK as

```
var PK = this;
```

**2.** In HTML code you don't need to call you functions using PK, just put the function's names:

```
<h2 id="popup" data-bind="event: { mouseover: showdiv, mouseout: hidediv }">
            Search
</h2>
```

**3.** In javasript code you have incorrect function name like 'hidedivOver', so you should rename this function to 'hidediv' or you can rename function 'hidediv' in HTML Code to 'hidedivOver'
**4.** You didn't create view model and didn't apply it to knockout
**END EDIT**
***Does it answer your question?***
Thanks.

Comment: Fixed now. It was the problem with the reference to ko.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your didn't call `applyBindings` function:

```
ko.applyBindings(PK);
```

Also I don't see how you initialize `PK` object.

Make sure that you call `applyBindings` when page is ready. For this you can put it at the botton of the page or inside `$(document).ready`.